# Java: Why does this unit testing not work (One to Many Relationship)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, dto, spring-boot-test

I have the following code that relates to java unit testing

```
    @Test
    public void testFindPetsByOwner() {
        CustomerDTO customerDTO = createCustomerDTO();
        CustomerDTO newCustomer = userController.saveCustomer(customerDTO);

        PetDTO petDTO = createPetDTO();
        petDTO.setOwnerId(newCustomer.getId());
        PetDTO newPet = petController.savePet(petDTO);
        petDTO.setType(PetType.DOG);
        petDTO.setName("DogName");
        PetDTO newPet2 = petController.savePet(petDTO);

        List<PetDTO> pets = petController.getPetsByOwner(newCustomer.getId());
        Assertions.assertEquals(pets.size(), 2);
        Assertions.assertEquals(pets.get(0).getOwnerId(), newCustomer.getId());
        Assertions.assertEquals(pets.get(0).getId(), newPet.getId());
    }
```

The result from that last assert.equals fails as seen below

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
<Click to see difference>
```

PetController.java

```
    @PostMapping
    public PetDTO savePet(@RequestBody PetDTO petDTO) {

        Pet newPet = new Pet();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(petDTO, newPet, "id");
        Pet savedPet = petService.save(newPet);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(savedPet, petDTO);
        return petDTO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/owner/{ownerId}")
    public List<PetDTO> getPetsByOwner(@PathVariable long ownerId) {

        List<Pet> petsByOwner = petService.getPetsByOwner(ownerId);
        List<PetDTO> petDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Pet pet:petsByOwner){
            PetDTO petDTO = new PetDTO();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(pet, petDTO);
            petDTOList.add(petDTO);
        }
        return petDTOList;
    }
```

PetService.java

```
    public Pet save(Pet pet){

        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(pet.getOwnerId()).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomerNotFoundException());

        pet.setCustomer(customer);
        customer.getPets().add(pet);
        customerRepository.save(customer);
        List<Pet> savedPets =  customer.getPets();
        Pet nPet =  savedPets.get(savedPets.size() - 1 );
        return nPet;
    }

    public List<Pet> getPetsByOwner(long ownerId) {
        return petRepository.findByOwnerId(ownerId);
    }
```

PetDTO.java

```
public class PetDTO {
    private long id;
    private PetType type;
    private String name;
    private long ownerId;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String notes;
// getters and setters
}
```

Pet.java

```
@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PetType type;

    private String name;
    
    private long ownerId;

    private LocalDate birthDate;

    private String notes;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pets")
    private List<Schedule> schedules;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
//getters and setters
}
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends Person {

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String notes;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
//getters and setters
}
```

Person.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {

    @Id
    // watch out if this generation strategy becomes a bug later
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected long id;
    @Nationalized
    private String name;
...
}
```

PetRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long> {

    List<Pet> findByOwnerId(long ownerId);
    
}
```

The related classes to the bug can be seen below. I suspect the bug could be related to pass by reference  in the unit testing.
NB: I have edited the post adding the relevant classes requested by one of the contributors

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it looks like you're calling `setOwnerId` only once for the first pet but not for the second. Pay attention that you're putting the "expected" and the "actual" in opposite places (hence the weird error). It should be `assertEquals(expected, actual)` meaning it should be: `Assertions.assertEquals(2, pets.size());`

Comment: Someone else wrote the unit testing which is part of an online course. My gut feeling is pass by reference but I could be wrong. I wrote the code in the other classes which is probably the location of the bug. Not sure

Comment: What guarantee do you have in the ordering of results when `petController.getPetsByOwner(newCustomer.getId());` is called? Is there any ordering applied in the SQL query? If not, there's likely no guarantee in the order which the results are returned.

Comment: @D-Dᴙum The order of the pets returned for ```petController.getPetsByOwner(newCustomer.getId)``` seems to have been constant when I used the IntelliJ debugger

Comment: I don't understand. When is the failure happening? When you run it in the debugger, or does the build server fail?

Comment: @D-Dᴙum I get the above result interms of Expected: 1, Actual: 2 when I the test in both debug or normal "run" mode. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you are assuming the ordering of the results when you call:

```
List<PetDTO> pets = petController.getPetsByOwner(newCustomer.getId());
```

Without seeing the query in the method `getPetsByOwner()` I would think that no ordering is being applied or is being applied in descending order. If you are not able to see the code, or there is no guarantee of any ordering then you should alter your test to something like:

```java
int pet1Id = newPet.getId();
int pet2Id = newPet2.getId();
for (PetDto pet : pets) {
    if (pet.getID() == newPet.getId() {
         //newPet specific tests
    } else if (pet.getId() == newPet2.getId() {
        // newPet2 specific tests
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected ID");
    }
}
```

Also ensure your values are ordered correctly in your assertions otherwise it will lead to confusing logging messages.

Comment: When I ran the test in debugger mode, newPet.getId = 2 and newPet2.getId = 2. This why I am thinking this might be related to pass-by-reference.

Comment: This is additional information to the original question. You are re-using `petDTO` during the saves. As well as making it difficult to follow the test it's not a good practice. Create two distinct petDTO objects and save them. I suspect during the first save the id is being populated on `petDTO` in the background by JPA (if I remember correctly how it works) - put a breakpoint in the `save()` method to confirm or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of creating another petDTO. The unit test no longer fails.